# Wifi disconnecting - Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

Tags: networking, wireless, disconnect

I am new to Ubutnu, recently installed Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS. Evrey time when I turn on My laptop, wifi works. But after few mintes, wifi disconnects and I have to start the laptop again. Any solution?
uname -r comment is showing "5.15.0-56-generic"
Thanks

I run the command `sudo apt-get install -y linux-firmware`, the out put is as below.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  systemd-hwe-hwdb
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
The following packages will be upgraded:
  linux-firmware
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 143 not upgraded.
Need to get 240 MB of archives.
After this operation, 72.7 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://nz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 linux-firmware all 20220329.git681281e4-0ubuntu3.9 [240 MB]
Fetched 240 MB in 32s (7,497 kB/s)                                             
(Reading database ... 195613 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../linux-firmware_20220329.git681281e4-0ubuntu3.9_all.deb ...
Unpacking linux-firmware (20220329.git681281e4-0ubuntu3.9) over (20220329.git681281e4-0ubuntu3.7) ...
Setting up linux-firmware (20220329.git681281e4-0ubuntu3.9) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-56-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-43-generic
```

not solved

Comment: It is worth checking that your network adaptors firmare is up to date via `sudo apt-get install -y linux-firmware`

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command.

Comment: @darth_epoxy thank you for your help. I tried to run this comment (edited in question), but not resolved.

Comment: Thanks @Pilot6 yes we should determine the driver. Try this at the command line `lspci -vvnn | grep -A 9 Network` as an alternative and let us know. Also, feel free to safely run the `sudo apt autoremove`

Comment: @Pilot6 I run the command (output is below) $ lspci -knn | grep Net -A3
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 3165 [8086:3165] (rev 79)
 Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wireless 3165 [8086:8110]
 Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
 Kernel modules: iwlwifi

Comment: @darth_epoxy 01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 3165 [8086:3165] (rev 79)
 Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wireless 3165 [8086:8110]
 Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
 Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
 Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
 Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 34
 Region 0: Memory at fea00000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
 Capabilities: <access denied>
 Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
 Kernel modules: iwlwifi

Comment: It seems that you may need to upgrade your kernel version.<br/>And so unfortunately there is no simple answer to your question.<br/>Read here [Canonical](https://ubuntu.com/security/notices/USN-5780-1)

Comment: Please add information to the question, not to comments.